# Finding a mixture of 1st and 0'th order Markov models that is closest to an empirical distribution

Tags: st.statistics, convex-optimization, markov-chains, nonlinear-optimization

I am interested in finding the distribution "$p^*$" closest to an empirical distribution $\hat{p}$ where $p^*$ is a mixture of first and zeroth order Markov models. That is, I want to find $$
p^* = \arg\min_p \sum_{i,j} D\left(\,\hat{p}(j|i)\, \| \, p(j|i) \,\right)
$$
subject to the following constraints

1. $p(j|i) = \alpha \cdot r(j) + (1 - \alpha) \cdot q(j|i)$
2. $r(j) \ge 0$ for all $j$
3. $\sum_j r(j) = 1$
4. $q(j|i) \ge 0$ for all $i$ and $j$
5. $\sum_j q(j|i) = 1$ for all $i$

where $\alpha$ is a mixture parameter in $[0,1]$ that is given and fixed.

I know I can hand this off to a solver, but I am actually interested in deriving the updates and writing the optimization procedure myself. Therefore, any assistance in this endeavor is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by update equations? Do you have a specific optimization method in mind? I‘m not clear about what the main question is here: is it how to write a convex optimizer? There is plenty of literature on that. Please clarify your question to indicate where the main problem lies.

Comment: Are you looking for a closed-form solution?

Comment: Closed form would be great. But I'm actually looking for a simple iterative method, like proximal gradient descent.

Comment: Why do you implicitily include the zeroth order term? Unless I'm missing something, the zeroth order term can simply be included in the first order term.

Comment: I was just going to comment the same. The model does not seem to be identifiable (and also not convex, contrary to what the tag suggests).

Comment: Corrent. The model is definitely not identifiable if "alpha" is a free parameter that is to be learned (since we can always set alpha to zero and run MLE).

Comment: The model is definitely not identifiable if "alpha" is a free parameter to be learned (since we can always set alpha to zero and do optimally). But here I assume "alpha" is given and fixed. We can tune alpha on held-out data.

Comment: There are two motivations for including the zeroth order component of the mixture model. 

1) Detrend the chain by identifying states which are commonly visited from all states. So "r" is a background distribution (noise), and "q" is the signal representing transitions which depend on context (the current state).

2) The 2nd motivation is statistical. By including a zeroth order component, we can better predict transitions out of sample, since our training data contains many states which were infrequently visited.

Comment: Question: is the problem convex if alpha is a given constant?

Comment: Even if alpha is fixed, and say $p$ is completely zeroth order. How can we decide which parts of $p$ to put into $q$ or $r$?

Comment: Okay, colinearity with the 0'th order model is a problem. But we can make some reasonable assumptions, that the Markov transition matrix has full rank, or large rank. In practice, I will tune alpha by making it as large as possible until performance on held-out data suffers. Note that mixtures of different order Markov models are used *all the time* in language modeling: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~klein/cs294-5/chen_goodman.pdf